# Paginação em JavaScript de asp:GridView

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte código:

JavaScript:

```
<script src="../js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#example2').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="example2" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="OnDataBound" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="40">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="hidden" id="ih1_<%#Eval("S_ID")%>" name="ih1_<%#Eval("S_ID")%>" value='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
        <input type="radio" id="rbTipo" name="rbTipo" value='<%#Eval("S_ID")%>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Desc" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TS_Desc" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

O meu problema e que a função em javaScript não funciona ou pelo menos não mostra os resultados esperados.

Eu queria que aparece-se a paginação na GridView, através do código javaScript que se encontra em cima. O que tenho de errado neste código? Existe alguma solução?

Os pulgins são do site AdminLTE.

Comment: tenta baixar uma versão atualizada no site official do plugin: http://datatables.net

Comment: Poste o código correto, eu tentei editar, mas você misturou algumas coisas no código quando colou ele aqui. Edite a pergunta e organize melhor para que seja possivel lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for só colocar paginação no gridview tem uma propriedade para isto.
`AllowPaging="True"`

Se não for isso, coloca mais detalhes do problema.